# Create a videoplayer with the LibVLC for android

Tags: java, android, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to creat a video player for an android app with the last LibVLC.

The problem is that I don't know how this lib works and I can't find sample to help me (as it is say here https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample)

So I try on my own to create the video player :

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IVideoPlayer, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener, IDelayController {

private static LibVLC LibVLC() {
    return VLCInstance.get();
}

private static MediaPlayer MediaPlayer() {
    return VLCInstance.getMainMediaPlayer();
}

@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ca start VideoPlayerActivity !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (!VLCInstance.testCompatibleCPU(this)) {
       // exit(RESULT_CANCELED);
        return;
    }
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mUri = extras.getParcelable(PLAY_EXTRA_ITEM_LOCATION);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oui ça start le VideoPlayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.player_test);
}

@Override
public  void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.player_surface_test);
    setSurfaceLayout(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_surface_frame_test);
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);
}

private static class ConfigureSurfaceHolder {
    private final Surface surface;
    private boolean configured;

    private ConfigureSurfaceHolder(Surface surface) {
        this.surface = surface;
    }
}

@Override
public void setSurfaceLayout(int width, int height, int visible_width, int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den) {

    /*if (width * height == 0)
        return;*/

    // store video size
    mVideoHeight = height;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoVisibleHeight = visible_height;
    mVideoVisibleWidth  = visible_width;
    mSarNum = sar_num;
    mSarDen = sar_den;
   Toast.makeText(this, "mVideoHeight = " + mVideoHeight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int configureSurface(Surface surface, final int width, final int height, final int hal) {
    if (AndroidUtil.isICSOrLater() || surface == null)
        return -1;
    if (width * height == 0)
        return 0;
    Log.i(TAG, "configureSurface: " + width +"x"+height);

    final ConfigureSurfaceHolder holder = new ConfigureSurfaceHolder(surface);

    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mSurface == holder.surface && mSurfaceHolder != null) {
                if (hal != 0)
                    mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(hal);
                mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width, height);
            }
            synchronized (holder) {
                holder.configured = true;
                holder.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        synchronized (holder) {
            while (!holder.configured)
                holder.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void eventHardwareAccelerationError() {
}

private void startVideo() {
    // LibVLC lib = new LibVLC();
    mMediaPlayer = VLCInstance.getMainMediaPlayer();
    Media media = new Media(VLCInstance.get(), mUri.getPath());
    media.parse();
    Toast.makeText(this, "le media dure : "+media.getDuration(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // Toast.makeText(this, "le media dure : "+media., Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
    //mMediaPlayer.setVideoTrackEnabled(true);
    //media.release();
   // mMediaPlayer.setEqualizer(VLCOptions.getEqualizer());
   // mMediaPlayer.setVideoTitleDisplay(MediaPlayer.Position.Disable, 0);
    int sw = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
    int sh = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
    VLCInstance.get().setWindowSize(sw, sh);
    mMediaPlayer.play();
    Toast.makeText(this, "le player a une valeur de : "+mMediaPlayer.isPlaying(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // media.parse();
   // media.release();
   // mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
   // mMediaPlayer.play();
}

private final SurfaceHolder.Callback mSurfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if(MediaPlayer() != null) {
            width = 100;
            height =100;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "surface width = "+width, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "surface height = "+height, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Surface newSurface = holder.getSurface();
            if (mSurface != newSurface) {
                mSurface = newSurface;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "surfaceChanged: " + mSurface, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LibVLC().attachSurface(mSurface, VideoPlayerActivity.this);
                mSurfaceReady = true;
                startVideo();
                //mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        if(MediaPlayer() != null) {
            mSurface = null;
            LibVLC().detachSurface();
            mSurfaceReady = false;
        }
    }
};

private final Handler mHandler = new VideoPlayerHandler(this);

private static class VideoPlayerHandler extends WeakHandler<VideoPlayerActivity> {
    public VideoPlayerHandler(VideoPlayerActivity owner) {
        super(owner);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        VideoPlayerActivity activity = getOwner();
        if(activity == null) // WeakReference could be GC'ed early
            return;

        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:
                activity.startVideo();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

public static void start(Context context, Uri uri) {
    start(context, uri, null, false, -1);
}

public static void start(Context context, Uri uri, boolean fromStart) {
    start(context, uri, null, fromStart, -1);
}

public static void start(Context context, Uri uri, String title) {
    start(context, uri, title, false, -1);
}

private static void start(Context context, Uri uri, String title, boolean fromStart, int openedPosition) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class);


    intent.setAction(PLAY_FROM_VIDEOGRID);
    intent.putExtra(PLAY_EXTRA_ITEM_LOCATION, uri);
    intent.putExtra(PLAY_EXTRA_ITEM_TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(PLAY_EXTRA_FROM_START, fromStart);
    intent.putExtra(PLAY_EXTRA_OPENED_POSITION, openedPosition);

    /*if (openedPosition != -1)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);*/
    Toast.makeText(context, "uri = "+uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    context.startActivity(intent);  // /!\ start the activity /!\ !!!
}

@Override
public void showAudioDelaySetting() {

}

@Override
public void showSubsDelaySetting() {

}

@Override
public void endDelaySetting() {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}
}
```

To start the videoPlayerActivity I call `start(Context context, Uri uri)` and it will creat the activity.

To resum this code :

After the `oncreat()` I call `onResum()` that will call a `mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);` and this callback call `startVideo()` that should start the video, but nothing start..

So if someone have a sample of how to create a simple video player with the last LibVLC or an idea where I fail, it would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below sample repo I created. It doesn't have all the bells and whistles, but it simply plays any valid video url. It uses a VLC SDK kindly provided by mrmaffen:

> https://github.com/gareoke/VLCPlayer

Comment: nice. but how do I access an IP camera from this and pass it authentication details? @gareoke

Comment: @gareoke Can it play video from local storage?

Answer (score 3):

2019 sees introduction of a VLCVideoLayout component that greatly simplifies the code required to embed VLC into android.

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples

The libVLC is provided by the official VideoLAN project hosted on BinTray.  See the build.gradle files for the link to the Maven repo and the package name/version.

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples/blob/master/build.gradle#L18
https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples/blob/master/java_sample/build.gradle#L34

Answer (score 2):

if someone is still looking for simple vlc player example Please have look at this [MyVlcPlayer](https://github.com/vkdinventor/MyVlcPlayer). It uses minimum code to play a video. To keep this project simple I have not added any video controller.

Comment: need video controller, could you please help me