# Android : How to get meta data using libvlc?

Tags: android, libvlc

With the the help of [Create a videoplayer with the LibVLC for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941173/create-a-videoplayer-with-the-libvlc-for-android), I succeeded to play online streaming from one of the icecast servers using vlclib in android application, but I am facing an issue now.

How can I retrieve the metadata like (song title , singer , album....etc) using vlcMediaPlayer object:

```
String url = "http://82.196.0.163:8000/dj.ogg";
LibVLC vlcMediaPlayer = VLCInstance.getLibVlcInstance();
vlcMediaPlayer.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
vlcMediaPlayer.playMRL(url);
```

Comment: Could you maybe give an example or describe it a bit more? So far I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Trilarion : I have edited the question please have a look at it again.

Comment: The edited question looks fine to me. Unfortunately I cannot help you.

Comment: @Trilarion : why ? What shall I do so that you can help me ? could you we chat if it is the only the way ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, I voted for reopening. No, nothing you can do because I simply don't know the answer. But don't worry. Given some time the question will very probably be opened again and given even more time, somebody with sufficient knowledge will come by and answer it. And additionally you can also try the stackexchange chat.

Comment: @Trilarion still no answer , what is your suggestion , what shall i do ? please advise me

Comment: The question is open and everyone could answer it but nobody does - this means nobody knows the answer and/or cares enough to answer. What you should do in that case? Ask somewhere else. Ask the creators of LibVLC for example.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use a different method for streaming and I don't know about that one, but this is a rather simple task if you use libvlc's `MediaPlayer` for playing remote streams.

The `Media` object used by `MediaPlayer` can have EventListeners set. One event type is `Media.Event.MetaChanged`, which triggers at song changes where new metadata is sent by the server:

```
mLibVLC = new LibVLC();
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);

Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, "http://82.196.0.163:8000/dj.ogg");

media.setEventListener(new Media.EventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onEvent(Media.Event event) {
         if (event.type == Media.Event.MetaChanged) {
             //New metadata received
             Media media = mMediaPlayer.getMedia();
             String songMetadata = media.getMeta(Media.Meta.NowPlaying);
         }
    }
});

mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
mMediaPlayer.play();
```

Keys other than `NowPlaying` also exist, but every IceCast server I worked with so far only delivered that one, with data consisting of artist and song title together as a single string.